# Windows Ubuntu subsystem, Nautilus running, but "operation not permitted" on server connect

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nautilus

Trying to run Nautilus on Windows 10 via the Ubuntu subsystem and Xming. It opens and looks good, but i had to install the entire ubuntu-desktop to get it the icons working.

Can browse local files fine, but when I try and connect to one of my servers I get:

"Sorry, could not display all the contents of "192.168.0.10 (sftp)": Operation not supported"

This is the command line output while running Nautilus:

> Unable to initialize DBus connection: Error sending credentials: Error
>   sending message: Invalid argument (nautilus:19): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **:
>   g_dbus_interface_skeleton_export: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION
>   (connection)' failed
>
> (nautilus:19): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable
>   to connect to session bus: Error sending credentials: Error sending
>   message: Invalid argument
>
> (nautilus:19): libunity-CRITICAL **: unity-launcher.vala:154: Unable
>   to connect to session bus: Error sending credentials: Error sending
>   message: Invalid argument
>
> (nautilus:19): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus:
>   Error sending credentials: Error sending message: Invalid argument
>
> (nautilus:19): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus:
>   Error sending credentials: Error sending message: Invalid argument
>
> ** (nautilus:19): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS
>
> ** (nautilus:19): WARNING **: Can not calculate _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS
>
> ** (nautilus:19): WARNING **: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA
>
> ** (nautilus:19): WARNING **: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it
>   failed: 'net usershare' returned error 1: ERROR: Could not determine
>   network interfaces, you must use a interfaces config line

All that is output before I try to connect to my server, which produces no output itself. But the last line sounds like it might be related to the problem. But I have no idea where this "interfaces config line" should be.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to do something wsl is not able to do out of the box. Sure, there are workarounds (you mentioned `Xming`), but the fact the feature is not officially suported means you'll stumble upon some errors while trying to set it up. For instance, I know wsl cannot use `ping` unless you run it with administrator rights in windows, maybe there is a similar issue with the `sftp` protocol ?. Could you try the `run as admin` option and see if it changes ?

Comment: I also noticed the mention of `dbus` in your error log. There is a known issue about it, you could read [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4rsmzp/bash_on_windows_getting_dbus_and_x_server_working/) about hw to enable it on windows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, no joy with running administrator, will look into the dbus issue this eve and get back to you.